# How can I combine errors?

Tags: r, error-handling

It's frustrating to have to fix issues one by one when the code had all the info to give exhaustive help from the first run.

```r
and1 <- function(a , b) {
  stopifnot(is.logical(a), is.logical(b))
  a & b
}

and1(0, 1)     # nope
#> Error in and1(1, 2): is.logical(a) is not TRUE

# fix it
and1(FALSE, 1) # still not good
#> Error in and1(FALSE, 2): is.logical(b) is not TRUE

# fix again
and1(FALSE, TRUE) # finally works
#> [1] FALSE
```

We can design complex combination but this looks bad and with more checks it would become very complicated very fast.

```
and2 <- function(a , b) {
  if (!is.logical(a)) {
    if (!is.logical(b)) {
      stop("\n`a` must be logical\n`b` must be logical")
    }
    stop("`a` must be logical")
  }
  if (!is.logical(b)) {
    stop("`b` must be logical")
  }
  stopifnot(is.logical(a), is.logical(b))
  a & b
}

and2(1,2)
#> Error in and2(1, 2): 
#> `a` must be logical
#> `b` must be logical
```

What's a good way to do this without the messy code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using {rlang}.

We feed unnamed expressions to the dots, they are tried separately and error messages are combined.

It wraps `rlang::abort()` and forwards its arguments to it (including named arguments passed to dots, such as `class` for instance).

I've added an optional `header` argument too.

```r
combine_errors <- function(
    ..., # unnamed expressions and named args to forward to abort()
    class = NULL,
    call,
    header = NULL,
    body = NULL,
    footer = NULL,
    trace = NULL,
    parent = NULL,
    use_cli_format = NULL,
    .internal = FALSE,
    .file = NULL,
    .frame = parent.frame(),
    .trace_bottom = NULL) {
  env <- parent.frame()
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  unnamed_dots <- dots[rlang::names2(dots) == ""]
  named_dots <- dots[rlang::names2(dots) != ""]
  named_dots <- eval(named_dots, env)
  err <- header
  for (expr in unnamed_dots) {
    new_err <- try(eval(expr, env), silent = TRUE)
    if (inherits(new_err, "try-error")) {
      err <- c(err, "!" = attr(new_err, "condition")$message)
    }
  }
  if (!is.null(err)) {
    names(err)[1] <- ""
    do.call(rlang::abort, c(list(
      err, 
      class = class,
      call = if (missing(call)) env else call,
      body = body,
      footer = footer,
      trace = trace,
      parent = parent,
      use_cli_format = use_cli_format,
      .internal = .internal,
      .file = .file,
      .frame = .frame,
      .trace_bottom = .trace_bottom
    ),
    named_dots))
  }
}
```

```
and3 <- function(a , b) {
  # should work with rlang or base
  combine_errors(
    header = "Multiple issues found:",
    if (!is.logical(a)) rlang::abort(c("`a` must be logical", i = "some info")),
    if (!is.logical(b)) stop("`b` must be logical")
  )
  a & b
}

and3(1,TRUE)
#> Error in `and3()`:
#> ! Multiple issues found:
#> ! `a` must be logical
#> ℹ some info
and3(FALSE,2)
#> Error in `and3()`:
#> ! Multiple issues found:
#> ! `b` must be logical
and3(1,2) 
#> Error in `and3()`:
#> ! Multiple issues found:
#> ! `a` must be logical
#> ℹ some info
#> ! `b` must be logical
```

Comment: I chose my own in the end because I can do things such as  `combine_errors(arg1 <- rlang::arg_match(arg1), ellipsis::check_dots_empty(), abort_not_boolean(arg2))`, which alternatives don't allow

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably make a named logical vector and then check that vector

```r
and1 <- function(a,b){
  
  checks <- c(
    "`a` must be logical" = !is.logical(a),
    "`b` must be logical" = !is.logical(b)
  )
  
  if(any(checks)) {
    paste("\n",names(checks[which(checks)]), collapse = "") |> 
      stop()
  }

  a & b
}

and1(1,2)
#> Error in and1(1, 2) : 
#> `a` must be logical
#> `b` must be logical
```

(format the error message as desired)

Comment: @Chris right, that's just me being lazy. in theory you could format with paste/collapse before passing to base stop() if you wanted to. 

edit: updated the main answer, comment code is super ugly lol

Comment: I think rlang::abort() will work fine here

Answer (score 4):

You can use `makeAssertCollection` from `checkmate`:

```r
and1 <- function(a , b) {
  logical_assertion <- checkmate::makeAssertCollection()
  checkmate::assert_logical(a, add = logical_assertion)
  checkmate::assert_logical(b, add = logical_assertion)
  checkmate::reportAssertions(logical_assertion)
  a & b
}

and1(0, 1)
#> Error in and1(0, 1) : 2 assertions failed:
#>  * Variable 'a': Must be of type 'logical', not 'double'.
#>  * Variable 'b': Must be of type 'logical', not 'double'.

and1(FALSE, 1)
#> Error in and1(FALSE, 1) : 1 assertions failed:
#>  * Variable 'b': Must be of type 'logical', not 'double'.

and1(FALSE, TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's a really cool system, you have to use only checkmate assertions but then it's really flexible, they don't need to be grouped and you can even collect errors from different functions as long as you pass the assertion collection too.

Comment: yes you are bound to `checkmate`, but in my experience I only rarely have to use other input checking methods

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the logical tests to integer, generating unique values for each combination of the tests which can then be found in a lookup table. (Just multiply the nth logical test by 2^(n-1)). Effectively you are converting your logical tests to n bits and counting in binary.

This might sound complex, but it's straightforward in practice and turns a branching problem into a linear one:

```r
and <- function(a, b) {
  
  if((valid <- is.logical(a) + 2 * is.logical(b)) < 3) 
    stop(c('Neither A nor B are logical', 
           "A is logical but B isn't",
           "B is logical but A isn't")[valid + 1])
  
  a & b
}

and(1, 0)
#> Error in and(1, 0) : Neither A nor B are logical
and(TRUE, 0)
#> Error in and(TRUE, 0) : A is logical but B isn't
and(0, TRUE)
#> Error in and(0, TRUE) : B is logical but A isn't
and(FALSE, TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Note that the error codes are fully informative, each is put out by the same call to `stop`, and there are no conditional branches beyond the single `if` statement at the top, which catches all the errors, allowing non-conditional code to be run at the end of your function.

Another option is to build the error message as you go along:

```r
and <- function(a, b) {
  err <- ''
  if(!is.logical(a)) err <- paste0(err, "\n'a' is not logical")
  if(!is.logical(b)) err <- paste0(err, "\n'b' is not logical")
  
  if(nchar(err)) stop(err)
  
  a & b
}

and(1, 0)
#> Error in and(1, 0) : 
#> 'a' is not logical
#> 'b' is not logical
and(TRUE, 0)
#> Error in and(TRUE, 0) : 
#> 'b' is not logical
and(0, TRUE)
#> Error in and(0, TRUE) : 
#> 'a' is not logical
and(TRUE, TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clever, but I'll need as many messages as possible combinations right ?

Comment: @moodymudskipper yes - I thought that's what you meant?

Comment: Sometimes that's useful, but if I am checking 5 arguments for instance that's a lot of combinations to hardcode, I'd be happy with a concatenation of the different messages in that case.

Comment: (FYI I've designed a solution too, that I'll post shortly, but I enjoy seeing different approaches and ideas)

Comment: @moodymudskipper I've included a second approach - is this similar to your own?

Comment: In some ways it is, since I end up pasting errors as you do. Your approach is more economic, it's good to avoid `try()` when you can deal with the logic more elegantly, but in many cases we want to use an existing checking function and we don't have the messages isolated from the tests and error triggering.

Comment: @moodymudskipper I guess your option is the kind of robust and properly traced solution one might employ in a low-level package, such as rlang itself. Well worth the upvote (+1), but possibly overkill as end-user code?

Answer (score 2):

Can't we just make an {rlang} `stop_if_not` function?

```r
stop_if_not <- function(...) {
  parent_env <- rlang::caller_env()
  dots <- rlang::enquos(...)
  
  idx <- !purrr::map_lgl(dots, rlang::eval_tidy)
  if (any(idx)) {
    error_msg <- purrr::map2(unname(dots[idx]),
                                 names(dots)[idx],
                                ~ c(x = paste0(
                                  deparse(rlang::get_expr(.x)),
                                  " is not TRUE"),
                                    if (nchar(.y) > 0) {
                                      c(i = .y)
                                      })
                             )

    rlang::abort(c(i = "Error in the following condition(s):",
                  unlist(error_msg)),
                  call = parent_env)
  }
}


and1 <- function(a , b) {
  stop_if_not(
    "`a` must be logical" = is.logical(a),
    is.logical(b)
    )
  a & b
}

and1(1, 2)
#> Error in `and1()`:
#> ! ℹ Error in the following condition(s):
#> ✖ is.logical(a) is not TRUE
#> ℹ `a` must be logical
#> ✖ is.logical(b) is not TRUE

and1(1, FALSE)
#> Error in `and1()`:
#> ! ℹ Error in the following condition(s):
#> ✖ is.logical(a) is not TRUE
#> ℹ `a` must be logical

and1(FALSE, TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There is this open issue : https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/1111 , but there is no intention of combining errors AFAICT

Comment: This solution is really good, if you combine it with the ability to name errors as in stopifnot() and Tan's solution it'd be even better

Comment: That should definitely be possible, I'll give it a try later :)

Comment: @moodymudskipper we can now pass named arguments to `stop_if_not()` and they render as info `ℹ` under each error `✖`. If we don't supply a name, just the error is rendered as is.